# Evaluate $\int\frac{\cos^2 x}{1-\sin x }dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

$\int\frac{\cos^2 x}{1-\sin x} dx $ can someone explain me how to solve this one and please show your complete solution? So am I supposed to make the numerator $1+sinx$? but I think that doesn't help. Should I do long division?

Comment: "I think that doesn't help": did you even try ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We know that $\displaystyle \cos^2 x = 1 - \sin^2 x = (1-\sin x)(1+ \sin x)$

Hence,
$$
\require{cancel}
\begin{align}
\int\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\sin x}\mathrm dx &= \int \frac{\cancel{(1-\sin x)}(1+\sin x)}{\cancel{1- \sin x}}\mathrm dx\\
&= \int \mathrm dx + \int \sin x\\
&= x - \cos x + \color{gray}{\mathcal C} 
\end{align}$$

---

**Aliter::** The same method in another approach:
$$\require{cancel} \frac{\cos^2 x}{1 - \sin x}\cdot \frac{1 + \sin x}{1 + \sin x} = \frac{\cancel{\cos ^2 x}\cdot (1 + \sin x)}{\cancel{\cos^2 x}} = 1 + \sin x$$

Answer (score 8):

$\int \frac{1-\sin ^2 x}{1-\sin x}dx=\int (1+\sin x) dx=x-\cos x+C_1$.

Comment: Shouldn't you at least explain?

Comment: @SixthOfFour What **exactly** is there to explain?? And even if there is something, this is so basic that it can safely be left to the OP to think about.

Comment: got it with an operator thanks!

Comment: @Mickey Uh? What do you mean "with an operator"?

Comment: @Timbuc so $\int\frac{1-sin^2x}{1-sinx}x\frac{1+sinx}{1+sinx}$ my professor calls it operator? is there another term?

Comment: @Mickey I don't know why you call that "with an operator" (not to mention that weird $\;x\;$ in the middle), but I can't see either how that'd help. What's been done here, as in the other answer, is to use a basic algebra formula of squares difference to get a pretty simple expression: $$1-\sin^2x=(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)$$

Comment: @Timbuc The fact that $cos^2x+sin^2x=1$ and $(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$ may be basic to you and me, and we may fail, because of that, to understand how it can be not so basic to someone else, and that someone can know these identities without actually understanding them and/or how they relate in this case. The OP specifically asked for an explanation. Had he not, I would have agreed with you.

Comment: @SixthOfFour I think you may have a point there, yet I think anyone dealing with integrals (or antiderivatives) has already done a good deal of basic algebra and trigonometry, so hints should be enough. Anymore, as in this case,is suspicious of being "do my homework for me", imo.

Comment: @Timbuc And you certainly have a point there.

Answer (score 1):

$$\int\frac{\cos^2x}{1-\sin x}dx=\int\frac{1-\sin^2x}{1-\sin x}dx=\int\frac{(1-\sin x)(1+\sin x)}{1-\sin x}dx=$$
$$=\int(1+\sin x)dx=\int1dx+\int\sin xdx=x-\cos x +C$$